# Impossible to save LaTeX file in Texmaker on Windows

Tags: errors, windows, texmaker

Yesterday, I downloaded the latest version of MiKTeX and Texmaker and started using XeLaTeX. Today, I am no longer able to compile or save any `.tex` file. When I try to do so, a message pops up: “The file could not be saved. Please check if you have write permission.”

Do you have any idea of how I could fix this problem?

Comment: With [TeXmaker 4.0.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html), save it as `.tex` extension otherwise it will pop up error. It is not saved as `.tex` automatically starting from new version as latex file can have any extensions `.cls` `.sty` `.dtx` etc..

Comment: Which windows? Did you install as a admin and work now as a non-admin (and the tex-file is in a system folder)?

Comment: Ok, I saved the file as .tex and now it works fine!

Comment: Not *too localized* at all – this is easily reproducible and will likely annoy many users; yet the author of Texmaker is unwilling to change it. (Voted to reopen.)

Comment: @ben I added the error message I’m getting, assuming you’re getting the same one? This way, people Googling that message will hopefully find this question.

Answer (score 12):

Starting from TeXmaker 4.0 built on `Qt5`, with [TeXmaker 4.0.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html), save it as `.tex` extension otherwise it will pop up error due to `Qt5 file dialog box`.

It is not saved as `.tex` automatically starting from new version(4.0) as latex file can have many extensions like `.cls` `.sty` `.dtx` etc..

**Update:**

"It's not a bug, but the default behavior of the Qt5 file dialog" as mentioned by Author in Issue Tracker.

<strike>Unfortunately this behaviour is missing at [changelog](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)</strike>.

Comment: They could certainly use a better error message, "write permission" is totally misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and I know how to fix it.
As you save the file, type: FILENAME.tex in the name box, and remember to put a dot between the file name and the format, usually you write tex.
Example:
PRIME NUMBERS.tex

Comment: A file name should never contain any spaces, nor special characters (like accents in vietnamese). Though most operating systems can handle it, it is very bad practice.