# I can't save a tex file

Tags: errors, pdf, texmaker

I'm really new to Texmaker but I already know the basics. The problem is that I can't even save my file, so I can't compile it. It says

```
The file could not be saved. Please check if you have write permission.
```

I have tried on diferent folders and none of them works. I'll apriciate any help.

Comment: what editor do you use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Are you suffering from same problem then use this medicine [Impossible to save latex file with windows?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106103/15717). Incase it works. we can make your question duplicate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've noticed similar errors with users that run out of disk space (or quota). (When that happens, the error messages are _very_ uninformative.)