# Drivers other than "pdftex.def" are not supported - - Need advice

Tags: texmaker, editors, epstopdf

Hey I'm configuring my TeXMaker 4.0.3, I did this few times and never had such a problem like that!

I have this message: 
`Drivers other than "pdftex.def" are not supported.`

PDF does not generate too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess: you must me be running .tex file with `[dvips]` or other drivers which are not matching the compilation engine. Both should match, for eg: run `latex sample` and then `dvips sample.dvi` and  finally `ps2pdf sample.ps` to get `sample.pdf`. remove any `epstopdf` package

Comment: know I have problem with save permisions... any idea where I can change thats. It is texmaker setting or windows setting?

Comment: I'm using Latex + dvips + ps2pdf + PDF, still the same problem. Here is mz preambuleŁ

Comment: _italic_ and **bold** text,
inline `code in backticks`,
and [basic links](http://www.sendspace.com/file/vsx3un)

Comment: For `save permisions` error: please update to current TeXmaker version [4.0.3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) and see more [Impossible to save LaTeX file in Texmaker on Windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106100/15717). Please make your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. then it will be easy to resolve the issue. Use some [simple examples at andy-roberts.net](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex) to compile and see the results.

Comment: Well, I have alredy Texmaker 4.0.3.

Comment: "basic link" include only preambule, my code is compilable I have been working all the time on in and it works.. Know I have just brand new work station and I can't configure texmaker, wrr

Comment: Did you install miktex or texlive and save the filename.tex .tex extension in TeXmaker ?

Comment: I've install miktex 2.9

Comment: and the pdftex.def package already install too

Comment: run `pdflatex sample2e` from [command line](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/command-prompt-frequently-asked-questions) to get `sample2e.pdf` then installation is prefect.

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how it approaches that step? Can u give me a guide, thanks for your help any way. I have instaled texstudio and it is compile but without graphics.

Comment: I am on Linux, So cannot give you windows screenshot help and even chat requires 20 rep. I have checked the preamble, it's loading `\usepackage[dvips]{color}` instead load `\usepackage{color}`, please cut down the preamble to a simple example from the above andy-roberts.net links.Ask 1-2 Good latex questions to get 20 rep after searching http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials

Comment: OK I'll some how fix this problem, reinstall texmaker and use my difriend very early templae also very complex, works! only sad think is I still realy don't know what was real issue.

Comment: Please answer yourself with the possible solutions that worked for you, otherwise if it's a problem unknown try closing the Q or deleting it.